# Using Alarm Manager to notify locations updates

Tags: android, geolocation, location, alarmmanager

Is it possible to setup Alarm Manager to notify when a location reaches my own location within a radius?

I have been searching with no luck. Maybe that is not the best way to do it, anyway.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have an app checking for this location? If yes, then yes you can.

Comment: Yes i do. My app currently tracks my location and generates random lat/long pairs nearby. Now i am interested on how to setup AlarmManager to notify when a random location gets too near. Any help?